# How retrieve raw JSON data in Selenium and Firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

How do you get raw JSON text from a web request using Selenium and the Firefox webdriver?

I'm trying to test a JSON API and confirm that specific data is being returned via the Python Selenium interface with Firefox. If I view the URL's page source in Chrome, I see content like:

```
{"id":10472}
```

However, if I call that same URL in Selenium+Firefox and access the document's source via `json_text = self.driver.page_source`, I get:

```
<html platform="linux" class="theme-light" dir="ltr"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none' ; script-src resource:; "><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://devtools-client-jsonview/css/main.css"></head><body><div id="content"><div id="json">{"id":10472}</div></div><script src="resource://devtools-client-jsonview/lib/require.js" data-main="resource://devtools-client-jsonview/viewer-config.js"></script></body></html>
```

It looks like Firefox is detecting the JSON content type and attempting to "help" my by wrapping it in a fancy HTML UI. Unfortunately, this makes it difficult to extract and validate the JSON programmatically from Selenium. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just locate the `WebElement` with the json?

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id('json').text # {"id":10472}
```